# MySQL SELECTing certain rows depending on IF/CASE statement

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, case, multiple-tables

something like the following is what I'm looking to do

```
SELECT id, status, Gid, Uid, note FROM notes LIMIT 10
```

but the status id could be different and it would need to be something like the following

```
SELECT a.id, a.status, a.Gid, a.Uid, a.note
FROM notes as a
WHERE
  IF(a.status < 2, DONT SELECT),
  IF(a.status == 2, 
    (SELECT approved FROM friends WHERE Uid = a.Uid AND Fid = ".$_SESSION['Uid'].") 
      IF(approved = 1, SELECT ROW, else DONT)
  )
  IF(a.status == 3, SELECT)
  IF(a.status == 4,
     (SELECT Gid FROM friends WHERE Uid = a.Uid AND Fid = ".$_SESSION['Uid'].")
     IF(Gid == a.Gid, SELECT ROW, else DONT)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I looked up the CASE command, but not sure how to use that, but I can see that being the way to do it, but yeah.. I'm not sure how to.
The above is an example of what I'm trying to do, the a.Uid can be different ids, so when the status == 2 or 4 we need to see if the viewing user is an approved friend or within the groupId (Gid)

any help fixing this query would be much appreciated.. I could change the notes table up a little if need be as its not in production yet, but is discouraged. I'm open to suggestions though

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Conditions that control whether a record should be selected or not belong in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I understand that, I was just posting an example query for what I was after.. I moved the "FROM notes" above the IF statements, and added the WHERE clause right after.. I'm still not sure how I would be able to select the correct rows depending on what the "status" column is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select a.id, a.status, a.Gid, A.Uid, a.note
FROM notes a
LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.Uid = a.Uid AND f.Fid = $_SESSION[Uid]
WHERE (a.status = 2 AND f.approved = 1)
OR a.status = 3
OR (a.status = 4 AND f.Gid = a.Gid)
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: that makes sense actually using a left join, I'll go test it out now and get back to ya. Thanks for the help!

Comment: from what I can tell its working out great! thanks for the help there man, I was getting ready to pull my hair out on a simple join query.. I guess i didnt think about using OR in the WHERE clause lol

Comment: FYI, another way to do it is with a UNION. Sometimes these can have better performance than OR in the WHERE clause, if you have an index on the status column.

Comment: yeah, I needed the status to have an index cause its the main column being called all the time. I havent used a UNION clause yet in mysql so I'd have to look up how to use them